# Collision avoidance system - image interpretation

Tags: computer-vision, robotics

I am refining an algorithm for collision avoidance I wrote for an ASV using a monocular camera.

In order to have a simple yet effective system, the algorithm relies on edge detection using a *Canny* filter, after proper erosion/dilation to remove noise and shading spots.
The final image is a black and white frame where, starting from the bottom, the first contour found and the upper part gets coloured in white while the rest is black: so black can be interpreted as "free space" whereas white as "obstacle".

The rover should use this reactive collision avoidance system to steer accordingly, avoiding close obstacles.

Now I am having some problems to decide how to actually find the way to go.

This is my approach so far.
The frame is split in columns whose width is exactly 1° relative bearing, then columns are grouped in three super-columns (corresponding to the directions *turn left, go on, turn right*) and the robot steers on the direction where the most black space is found.

Do you have any other idea on how to find where to steer/proceed given the output of this algorithm? 
Thank you

**Image processing example**

1. initial frame

[image: initial frame]

2. filtering

[image: filtering]

3. occupancy frame

[image: occupancy frame]

4. column divisions

[image: column divisions]

5. command -> steer left